# Trouble proving argument as valid

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I need help converting this argument: "  If I don’t pay my income taxes, then I file for an extension or I  am a felon.  I’m not a felon and I didn’t file for an extension.  Therefore, I paid my income taxes." into propositional logic and proving it as valid.
This is what i believe it looks like symbolised: ~p->(q v r), ~(r & q), therefore p.  every truth table i construct proves it as invalid and every truth table generator i use proves it as invalid. But my answer key says its valid, so perhaps im symbolising it wrong? I would really appreciate some help here.

Comment: What are the $p,q,r$ symbols?

Comment: $\neg r \land \neg q \iff \neg (q\lor r)$.

Comment: sorry for that, P would be paying my income taxes, Q would be filing for an extension and R would be being a felon. Is the way i symbolised it correct?

Comment: "I’m not a felon and I didn’t file for an extension" would be (~R & ~Q), using your symbols.

Comment: just drew the truth table for it and its valid! thank you so much!!